# Resource not found (resource=<my-subscription-id>) error when creating subscription in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

This issue happens when we create a subscription with delivery type 'Write to Big Query', and select 'Use topic schema' and create.

Subscription to be created

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when you don't add schema to your topic and create subscription for that topic.
The resource not found refers to pubsub schema.
Please review your schema and check if the topic is created from pubsub schema to avoid this issue.